# Aiogram, как реализовать запись в бд данных вводимыми пользователями?

Tags: telebot, aiogram, бот, sqlite3

пишу бота на aiogram
В моём боте есть кнопка "Введите свой кошелёк"
Юзер вводит свой кошелёк, и нужно сделать так, чтобы этот кошелёк сохранялся в бд рядом с user_id этого пользователя
Попрошу вас показать пример кода для реализации этой функции/способа(не знаю как правильно описать)
Заранее благодарен

Comment: начать можно с [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL).

Comment: милионны примеров в интернете. Научитесь гуглить